# CouchbaseLite 1.3.0 view querying id of doctype

Tags: couchbase-lite, couchbase-view

I am using couchbase lite 1.3.0 for an ios app. I am saving the model objects as docs in the db. However I am changing the 'doctype' dynamically while saving. Upon querying with 'docType' id , the cbl view emits wrong/unmatching 'docType'. Couldn't figure out how to fix this.

```
[view setMapBlock: MAPBLOCK({

    if ([doc[@"docType"] isEqual: @"docType1"])
 {
        emit(doc, nil);
    }
})
 version: @"1"];


CBLQuery* query = [view createQuery];

query.descending = NO;

CBLQueryEnumerator* result = [query run: &error];

for (CBLQueryRow* row in result) {

//The rows emitted doc of 'doctype2'

}
```

Comment: Couchbase Lite 3.x does not exist, and your question needs more detail about what you are doing

Comment: details added...

Comment: Did you recently change your map block without adjusting the version number?  That could cause incorrect results.  Also, where are you getting the 3.0.1 number from?  Couchbase's latest released version is 1.4.1.

Comment: @Borrden. If I create views newly everytime , does it solve? i.e is by deleting the existing one?

Comment: Sorry abt the version

Comment: @borrrden reg your question , it is the same version we are setting map block

Comment: If you change the view contents you must also change its version to trigger a restart of the indexing, or your view will contain invalid entries.  Also beware that 1.3 is coming up on its end of life in a few months.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `docType` is OK I think, the problem is you `map` function is hard coded against a query parameter which is not encouraged and also you `emit` a full doc as well.

I can achieve what you are trying to do with this:

```
[view setMapBlock: MAPBLOCK({
    emit(doc[@"docType"], nil);
})
version: @"1"];
```

and then query using the `docType1` as a parameter, if you need the `doc` just set the `preFetch to`true`

I'm aware that this will introduce 'redundancy' to what you want, but I think it solves the problem